# How do I access a string Resources file throughout a solution

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, mvvm

I have a multi project solution (let's say that these are imaginatively named Project A-F) to which I have added one more project (projectG  created as a class library) into which I would like to add resource files that could be used by all of the projects in the solution and which could be translated into other languages in due time.

In my ProjectG I have created a new resouces file called 'SolutionStrings' into which I have added several strings. How do I actively reference the resource strings defined in the 'SolutionStrings' resource file in other projects with the solution.

I have read various posts that suggest that I need to create a class with ProjectG that then has a property representation of the resources but when I have tried this I see warnings pointing out that that I can't expose the resource type outside of the project.

I pretty sure that I'm missing something simple here, but am not exactly sure what.  Might I ask those of you with a bit more experience in this area to point me in the correct direction.

Thanks

This is for a wpf solution using mvvm.  At some point I would like to be able to reference  string resources defined in projectG in the xaml of user controls in the project containing the views, so that the solution can be localised relatively easily.

Comment: What's wrong with going to Properties->Resources and creating publicly visible strings?

Comment: Well nothing, save for the fact that I envisage that there will be several tens, or hundreds of these and from what I have read resource files are the best thing to have in these circumstances.

Comment: Then perhaps you would want to create a custom binding that loads a file with key/value pairs and pulls out the string values by key?  You can access that binding from whatever assembly you're in.  And since it's using a single file (xml, xls, whatevs) it would make it easy to version changes.

Comment: Try this codeproject article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123460/Simplest-Way-to-Implement-Multilingual-WPF-Applica

Comment: You could use the [WPFLocalizationExtension](https://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/) for localization purposes. It's handy to use and provides many useful features.